# AnimationRunning option of Animate misbehaving

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, animation, options, user-interface

This simple example gives a strange error.

```
DynamicModule[{Go = True}, 
  Animate[
    EventHandler[
      Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], t]], 
      {"MouseClicked" :> (Go = False)}], 
    {t, 0, 8}, 
    DefaultDuration -> 30, 
    AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[Go]]]
```

A message window pops up which says:

> An unrecognized option name ("AnimationRunning") was encountered while reading a AnimatorBox.

And my message handler doesn't work (it's supposed to stop the animation when I click it). If I replace `Dynamic[Go]` with simple `Go`, there are no messages and the animation works correctly (but the message handler is disconnected, of course). So the option *per se* is perfectly recognized, and the problem is with `Dynamic`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works fine in version 11.3 (Windows 10 - 64 bit).

Comment: I've got version 9 for XP Win32. Can't upgrade.

Comment: Guess I need a workaround.

Comment: AnimatorBox didn't have an AnimationRunning option in v9.  Animate (the box generator function) does.  Using Dynamic as a rhs is supported until v10, IIRC.

Comment: You mean "is not supported until v10"? Or I don't get you.

Comment: Sorry about the typo.  "not supported".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around:

```
Manipulate[EventHandler[Graphics[Rotate[Rectangle[], t]], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> (Go = Not[Go])}],
  {{t, 0}, 0, 8, Animator[##, DefaultDuration -> 30, AnimationRunning -> Go] &}, 
  {{Go, True}, None}, 
  AppearanceElements -> {}]
```

[image]

Comment: So this was basically a scoping problem with weird symptoms. The ghost control part turned out to be the main one. Thanks!